# Error 403 on form submit

Tags: php, html

I've got a problem with a form in the administration area of my website. I use it for changing the displayed HTML text, it is written in PHP and connects to a MySQL database.

```
echo "<form action=\"index.php?kat=infos&aktion=upd&kategorie=$kategorie\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\">\n";
echo "<table border=\"0\">\n";
echo "<b>$kategorie</b>\n";
echo "<tr><td><b>Information:</b></td><td><textarea name=\"info\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"7\">$info</textarea></td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Editieren\" /></td></tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
echo "</form>\n";
```

If i enter some small sentences like "This is a test text only." and click the submit-button, the index.php accepts the data and inserts it into the database just as it should. But if I enter a longer text like the disclaimer from http://www.juraforum.de/disclaimer_muster/ I get a Error 403 on form submit.
I do not think it is because of the longer text, because if I write some longer random text in there it works, too.

I hope you can help me with this one.

Comment: Does it work for a short line in a different language?

Comment: I had a similar problem once, it turned out to be related to multipart forms.

Comment: It worked with short english and german sentences, I have also tried it with äöüß in it, too. It's just that I cannot get it to work with texts like the example disclaimer from <juraforum.de> which I would like to use on my page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 403 [Status Code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) means:

> **10.4.4 403 Forbidden**
>
> The server understood the request, but
>   is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the
>   request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the
>   request method was not HEAD and the
>   server wishes to make public why the
>   request has not been fulfilled, it
>   SHOULD describe the reason for the
>   refusal in the entity. If the server
>   does not wish to make this information
>   available to the client, the status
>   code 404 (Not Found) can be used
>   instead.

The disclaimer seems to contain several HTML tags and they apparently get printed unescaped on the page.

My wild guess is that there's a piece of software installed on the server (possibly [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/)) that rejects the input because it considers it's an attempt to perform a XSS attack. You can confirm (or reject) this hypothesis by temporarily removing the < and > symbols before pasting it into the textarea.

Comment: OK, after removing the < and >, the form submit worked. But it also worked with a short line like <p>Test</p>

Comment: Things you can try:

1. Escape all variables with htmlspecialchars()
2. Ask your hosting provider if they have a security module
3. Inspect the error log

Comment: Mine problem is bit weird it is giving me 403 when i submit url in form, removing all url in field value it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that works for me:

Apparently mod_security did not like that the name of the textarea was "info". After changing it to "text" there were no more problems and I can now enter any text I want.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to this to say that I also had this problem and it turned out to be a mod_security rule that false-positived, that caused the problem. The host of the site was able to whitelist the domain against the particular rule. The rule was apparently 211580 - "COMODO WAF: SQL Injection Attack".

Comment: adding a copy of the security rule would help others avoid the issue

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Changing the name of the textarea from "info" to something else seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this issue when you submit a form with a url. posting urls might be blocked in server for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I was also suffering with this problem, until I worked out that having a combination of HTML tags and slashes in a `<textarea>` field caused it. This was also code that was to be inserted into a database.

I was already using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Or

```
1.Use [strip_tags()][2]
2.Use [HTML Purifier][1] (recommended)


http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php
http://htmlpurifier.org/
```