# 403 on form submit, 200/302 with cURL/wget

Tags: php, http-post, form-submit, httpresponse, http-status-code-403

I have a form with many inputs. Some named "date", "type" etc.

The form action points to `http://www.xxx.com/admin/links/create`, via `POST`.

When I try to submit it (having required fields populated correctly), I get a `403` response.

In the following cases, I get either `302` or `200` response codes (depending on log-in cookie):

- plain `http://www.xxx.com/admin/links/create` URL in address bar (I know that's GET);
- using [websniffer](http://web-sniffer.net/) (GET & POST)
- curl/wget from local

I checked the permissions, the .htaccess (I only have FTP access to web-root) and [various](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/) [other](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-access/) places and everything *looks* fine.

I *hope* it's not [naming collision of the inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092056/error-403-on-form-submit) (actually, I do hope so, because that'll be easy to fix).

---

**All the above happen in `production`, which is `Linux` (Apache/2.0.51 on Fedora). Everything works fine on `local`, which is `Windows`.** Don't tell me it's permissions...

---

Does somebody know what could be the cause for this - in my own perception - strange behavior?

Comment: It was that blasted mod_security of which I've heard so many (horror) stories. I'll be back with a complete answer in some 6 hours (my rep's < 100).

Comment: btw, the linked sniffer doesn't function properly, try this [web sniffer](https://websniffer.cc/) out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Culprit: Apache's mod_security.

I didn't have that module installed in my Windows machine (that's why it worked locally), but the server had it installed.

Here's what I did:

- I checked the access logs. Found this:

  `[...] mod_security: Access denied with code 403. Pattern match "!(^application/x-www-form-urlencoded$|^multipart/form-data;)" at HEADER("Content-Type") [...] [uri "/admin/links/create"] [...]`
- As I don't know how to handle mod_security (yet!), I removed it altogether, and it worked. In your `.htaccess`:

> ```
> <IfModule mod_security.c>
>   SecFilterInheritance Off
> </IfModule>
> ```

Of course, you can pin-point your Apache targets only to apply that rule to certain files/folders using directives.

Some links that might help:
http://community.mybb.com/showthread.php?tid=7592
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-to-22-dashboard-not-working
http://energy-4-3.com/uncategorized/mod_security-access-denied-with-code-403-pattern-match-http/
http://www.modsecurity.org/ (homepage)