# Error 403 triggered when posting URL's via form with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, forms, url

I am encountering a 403 Forbidden error when posting URL's via a form using PHP on an apache shared host.

From an existing question ( [Error 403 on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092056/error-403-on-form-submit) ) this is most likely caused by mod_security installed on the server.

As I am using shared hosting, I'm not able to disable the module easily, so I implemented a [JavaScript solution](http://edrackham.com/javascript/solution-to-form-submit-403-error/) to strip the **http://** before posting the data.

This worked for a while, but unfortunately, the error is still being triggered by some longer url's.

Are there any further methods I can use to cleanse the URL before posting it so that it won't trigger a security module like this?

Comment: as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 a `403` means that `the server can be reached, but the server declined to allow the requested access.`

Comment: The form's action...does that resolve?

Comment: Please post example form submit data, so that we can better assist you

Comment: @YzmirRamirez Could you expand further about how I could check this?

Comment: @pzirkind The URL that triggers the error is similar to this: "http://www.website.com/2011/10/04/article-that-was-written-on-a-certain-topic/".

Most other URL's are not triggering the error.

Comment: @icarus thanks, is there unescaped html being sent (see the answer to the question you referenced)

Comment: Use Firebug in Firefox or turn on Web Developer view in Chrome or Fiddler in Windows to see what the request is when you submit.  What does the `action=" - what is here? - "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had a similar issue and what I did was ask my hosting provider to add an exclusion to mod_security for that specific page, and it was fixed. The alternative was to disable mod_security, which they did not want to do :)

Another thing you might try is having a Javascript action on the submit buttons, which does a base64 encode of the URL, and then submits the form with that encoded value. Then, on the server side, you decode it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much BlunT. I tried messing around with a few different methods to change the URL's before they were posted but it was beyond me. In the end, I did as you suggested and contacted my hosting company to get mod_security disabled on the specific pages - which they were happy to do, and this solved the issue.

Comment: Usually if a URL posts correctly from say a browser but not from a script, it is indeed a MOD SECURITY issue. The other way to overcome this instead of disabling mod security is to see what Headers the browser is sending and then modify the Headers sent by the script to match.