# Submit Form 403 Forbidden

Tags: javascript, forms, http-status-code-403

I have a Squarespace site where I am trying to test the contact form. I've been trying to submit the form via JavaScript in the browser console, but I get a 403 forbidden.

I've looked at this question [Error 403 triggered when posting URL's via form with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250412/error-403-triggered-when-posting-urls-via-form-with-php), the site linked, and similar questions to no avail.

Is my only resort contacting squarespace to get an exclusion of mod_security on that page?

Thanks

```
document.getElementsByName('fname').value='FirstNameTest';
// other fields
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Comment: Maybe this article will help http://edrackham.com/javascript/solution-to-form-submit-403-error/

Comment: Yeah I went through that before.. is it just wanting me to put the url w/o 'http://' in a form input somewhere? I tried that, otherwise I don't quite understand what it's saying to do

Comment: It says change the mod_security (an Apache module)  or if you don't have access to change mod_security use javascript to remove  ‘http://’ part of the URL. if you can past your full form code with html part maybe I can help you.