# 403 error when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Recently, when pressing the "submit" button on the form on [this page](http://isometricland.net/keyboard/keyboardsubmit.php) I get a 403 error. When directly accessing [the new page](http://isometricland.net/ssi/emailprocessor_keysub.php) by typing the URL into the browser I don't get the message and it loads properly.

I have these lines in the first PHP page:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="keyboard_submit">
...
<p><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Submit_Scheme();"/><input type="button" value="View Flat File" onclick="View_Flatfile();"/><input type="reset" value="Reset Fields"/></p>
```

In my Javascript file I have this function:

```
function Submit_Scheme()
{
    var submission_string = Parse_Fields()
    var SubmitForm = document.forms[SubmitName]
    SubmitForm.submission_code.value = submission_string
    SubmitForm.action = '../ssi/emailprocessor_keysub.php'
    SubmitForm.target = ''
    SubmitForm.method = 'POST'
    SubmitForm.submit()
}
```

I have read some explanations in other posts, but do not understand them or how to implement the changes. I would appreciate some help.

Error Message:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /ssi/emailprocessor_keysub.php on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: have you checked you .htaccess where your file /ssi/emailprocessor_keysub.php is placed ?

Comment: try remove `..` in `SubmitForm.action`

Comment: You may be running into the limit of the number of elements you may submit. Look into max_input_vars.

Comment: added the real message from your page here, this is much helpful for anybody to solve the issue.

Comment: That's strange, I tried ajaxing the page through the console and everything seemed to be fine....

Comment: It would be helpful to see the contents of `emailprocessor_keysub.php`

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092056/error-403-on-form-submit

Comment: There is no .htaccess file in that folder. I get the same error if emailprocessor_keysub.php is blank, so its contents are not the issue. @suchit: I looked at that page but didn't understand what to do. I should also note that the script worked without errors when I originally wrote it several years ago.

Comment: go to your .htaccess file in wamp/lamp and if you have <limit GET > only the make it  <limit GET POST>. if your form data is correct now it should work.

Comment: @Robbert may have been correct. I changed the name parameter of the inputs to id parameters instead, and used jscript to collect all the data into a single container. It works now.

Answer (score -3):

you are submitting the form on a file that is not found on the server.

try and give the absolute path for the file that you are submitting the form to

(/ssi/emailprocessor_keysub.php)

Comment: 403 forbidden does not mean file not found.  The 404 part of the error comes because there is no error document that can display a custom 403 error page.