# 403 Forbidden Error on submit form

Tags: php, html, forms, http-error

I am getting 403 Forbidden error when submit a form with large number of fields
my server configuration is bellow

```
execution_time 180
memory_limit 256M
post_max_size 256M
max_input_vars 2000
```

If I remove some fields from the form its working fine.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you look at what a 403 is, its more to do with denying access because apache cannot access the resource you are trying to access.

Comment: this problem is appears only live server in dev server its working fine with same number of input fields

Comment: Try to remove one at a time, see if you are able to locate which field is creating the error.

Comment: _Dev works - Live does not_ Then compare all your Apache and PHP configs, there will be a difference in config or permissions on the 2 environments

Comment: @doveyg I have near about 1500 fields in this form

Comment: You've figured out a group of fields which turn it from broken code to working code... Start with that group. Can I ask, what are you doing with ~1500 fields?

Comment: @doveyg In this system admin can ad category and sub category. each category used in front end for 7 days monday to sunday, for each day there are 4 input fields :)

Comment: I'd try checking that it isn't mod_security - quite a lot here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092056/error-403-on-form-submit

Comment: Please list the result of "apachectl -M" (list of modules). Also check if Suhosin is activated and if so increase the suhosin.get|post.max_vars setting.