# 403 forbidden error when submitting a form with HTML tags

Tags: php

Thank you for your precious time. I want to submit a form using Ajax Post Method.There are a form field for html code (it can be fontawesome, iframe, js code). Now you have to submit the phone and capture the data from the other side. `Print_r()` does not show any result in the file through which I will receive the data of the form. `Print_r($_POST)` when submitting form with HTML code; Even if it does, it does not show any result. Everything works fine on localhost but shows 403 forbidden error when I upload to my project server.

Comment: Authentication seems to be enabled in the server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2092197/231316), one possibility is that something like mod_sec is getting in the way.